# dev pool socket error

Tags: mining, xmr-stak-amd

I have been experiencing a problem with my mining rig and was wondering if anyone has ran into the same problem. I am using XMR-stak 2.2.0 and sometimes XMR-stak restarts because my hashes drops below the threshold that I set.  In my logs I noticed that when this happens, I get the following error:

> Dev pool socket error - mining on user pool

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

from reading [this](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/issues/192) issue thread it appears to be hardware related make sure to double check your equipment and overclocks if you have them also if you're exceeding the wattage of your PSU.